# @wired method not detecting reactive parameter change when calling refreshApex

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, refreshapex

I have observed something really weird for which I haven’t found an explanation yet. I have a component (`parentComponent`) containing a subcomponent (`childComponent`).

The `childComponent` subcomponent has a `@wired` function retrieving data from the database, which is working correctly when `childComponent` is loaded:

```
@wire(myServerMethod, {param: '$myParamProperty'})
myWiredFunction(result) {
   if (result.data) {
      this.myWiredProperty = result;
      console.log(‘Got the response from the server’);
      ...
}
```

`myWiredFunction` is returning the data from the server as expected, and I put `result` in a private property (`myWiredProperty`) so that I can call `refreshApex` later. So far so good.

When the user does something in the `parentComponent`, we want the `childComponent` to refresh the data from the database. For that, the `parentComponent` wants to pass a new value to the `childComponent`, which will be used in the @wired function to retrieve the data. So we pass the new value from the `parentComponent` to the `childComponent` to put it in `myParamProperty`, which is wired to the wired function and made reactive as can be seen: `{param: ‘$myParamProperty’}`

I could pass the new value from the `parentComponent` to the `childComponent` through a public property and use reactivity, I know, but for now I am forcing the property refresh through a public function that `childComponent` is exposing, and which `parentComponent` is calling imperatively when it wants `childComponent` to re-query the data from the database.

In `parentComponent`:

```
this.template.querySelector('c-child-component).refreshProperty(this.value);
```

In `childComponent`:

```
@api
refreshProperty(newValue) {
   this.myParamProperty = newValue;
   refreshApex(this.myWiredProperty);
}
```

So, if I update `myParamProperty` and then call `refreshApex`, that in theory should re-query the data through the wired function using the new value passed as the parameter.

Well, this is not working as expected. I may be overlooking something obvious, but if I check the value in `myParamProperty` just before calling `refreshApex`, I can see the new value as expected. Then `refreshApex` makes the wired function `myWiredFunction` to be re-invoked as expected, but the result returned by the LDS is the same as it was before, which means that nothing inside the wired function is run (i.e. the promise containing the console log with `‘Got the response from the server’` is not run).

So the wired function will not be run if the cache returns the same value we had before, but why is it returning the same result if I am passing a different parameter (`myParamProperty`)? Should that not make the cache/server return a different value?

As I can see the logs on the server side, in the Apex method, the first thing a do is inspect the value being received from the client. And here is my surprise: the value received by the server is the value of `myParamProperty` before it was updated.

That explains why the server is not returning a different result, but why is the property value lost in the communication between the client and the server?

So in summary:

1. I inspect the value of `myParamProperty` → it contains the new value
   as expected.
2. I call `refreshApex` → the wired function is re-invoked.
3. I check the logs on the server side → the parameter received is the
   old value.

I have a workaround which is working consisting of calling the same Apex method through an imperative call from JS. In this case the property is being sent to the server correctly and everything works as expected, but feels like a redundant solution when I have the wired function retrieving the data correctly the first time.

Apologies for the long post, I hope I have explained everything clearly! I would appreciate any thoughts, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This is an excellent first question. If you haven't yet, feel free to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. We hope you find your experience here pleasant!

Answer (score 0):

When you first assign the property value, then call `refreshApex` immediately, the wire handler hasn't had a chance to be notified of the change yet, as this happens later in the LWR life cycle, so it sees the old value. It also has some kind of "debouncing" effect to prevent infinite recursion on wire calls. The net effect is that you'd need another `refreshApex` later to fix this.

Instead, call `refreshApex` only if the value hasn't changed:

```
if(this.myParamProperty === newValue) {
  refreshApex(this.myWiredProperty);
} else {
  this.myParamProperty = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, tried this but now the wire handler is not being called (not creating logs on the server). That is what I was expecting initially, not to have to call refreshApex because just updating `this.myParamProperty` (made reactive in the wire handler call) should re-call the server automatically, but that is not happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DannyMarfil I'll write up a demo today. Give me a bit.

Comment: @DannyMarfil So, I built a bare-bones demonstration of this, and as I expected, the wire method is triggered correctly without refreshApex, and refreshApex was actually causing an error. So, I can't tell you what the problem is, but I can tell you this is *not* the problem. It's probably a typo or some kind of race condition. If it's possible, you can send me a copy of the code offline and I'd be happy to review it. Email's in my profile.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sfdcfox, email sent :-)